# How to fix the error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql

In below java code, whenever i try to save my code. i get the error `:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

```
 conn =JavaDb.ConnectDB();
   int p =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to 
    Save?","Saved",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(p==0){
      try {
        st = (Statement)conn.createStatement ();

       String queries = "insert into 

 invoice(Invoice_no,Date,Reference_no,Job_no,Destination,bl_no,Consignee,
 Items,Description,Quantity,Container,Rate,total_rate,clearingTxt,
shippingTxt)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(queries);
        pst.setString(1,invoTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(2,refTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(3,jobTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(4,destiTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(5,blTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(6,consigneeTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(7,itemTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(8,desc.getText());            
        pst.setString(9,QUANT.getText()); 
        pst.setString(10,cont.getText()); 
        pst.setString(11,rateTxt.getText()); 
        pst.setString(12,RATEtXT.getText()); 
        pst.setString(13,clearingTxt1.getText()); 
        pst.setString(14,shippingTxt.getText()); 
       pst.execute();   
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data Saved Successfully");
    st.close();
```

Comment: The error is as : Got an exception!   
     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
     Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
     (`emmess`.`invoice`, CONSTRAINT `invoice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bl_no`) 
    REFERENCES `file` (`bl_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Do you understand what a foreign key constraint is? And what it means for such a constraint to fail?

Answer (score 0):

bl_no is the sixth parameter in your query and passed value is

```
pst.setString(6,consigneeTxt.getText());
```

Is it right value you are passing?